# What does pornography and obscenity mean in Bangladesh and India?

Tags: bangladesh

Can intent matter in these cases for example if someone accidentally sends a picture without their bra. would that constitute pornography or obscene content ? in India and Pakistan it seems to be the case (IT act , pocso act and IPC obscenity)

the Pornography Control act of 2012 Bangladesh is much broader since it criminalises all aspects of pornography but it seems vague in its defonition of  pornography